# How to solve FRM:40105- Unabel to resolve reference to item problem?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I am new in Oracle forms and reports. I am facing this error.
I have created Employees data block and displaying it to the canvas. I triggered my module as new form instance with execute_query.  Then took one display text item and set it's database as no and set this name as search_box and another one is push button, I set it's name as search.

In search block button I have triggered this When button pressed and wrote this code.

```
begin
    set_block_property('EMPLOYEES',default_where,'EMPLOYEE_ID='||':search.search_box');
    go_block('EMPLOYEES');
    execute_query;
    set_block_property('EMPLOYEES',default_where,'');
    end;
```

My Employee_Id is one of my block item but still i can't understand where should I fix to solve this problem.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this - based on Forms Help which says:

```
Set_Block_Property('emp', ONETIME_WHERE, 'deptno <= :dept.deptno');
```

Also, you'd rather use `onetime_where`.

Therefore:

```
begin
  set_block_property('EMPLOYEES', onetime_where, 'EMPLOYEE_ID = :search.search_box');
  go_block('EMPLOYEES');
  execute_query;
end;
```

---

Saying that you can't make it work ... well, I can. Here's a demo.

[image]

Comment: I tried your code and this happened ,bad bind_variables, search.search_box  at line 2

Comment: Fixed; have a look, please.

Comment: still same error. My search_box data type is number , I don't know what to do.

Comment: The solution is , set_block_properties('EMPLOYEES',onetime_where,'EMPLOYEE_ID=:search_box');

Comment: If that's so, then it means that block you previously used isn't SEARCH. By the way, I created a form which does what you described and - if done properly - it works as expected. Have a look at edited answer (which contains block name, so - as I said - you've done something wrong).

Comment: My bad, I didn't separate the search,search_box item to control block. Thanks!